# PLSQL variable doesn't get assigned by the given value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to assign a value from a table type variable to a varchar2 type table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_SYS IS
   TYPE line_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE test(
   val_ OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
   temp_val    VARCHAR2(4000);
   svalues_    line_Table;
BEGIN
   svalues_(1) := '! -$FILE_LINE=EXT01;2017-01;2017-
   12;JJ01;;4021;;;;;;;;;;;;USD;;;;;;;;1000;1000;; -';

   temp_val := svalues_(1);
   val_ := temp_val;
END test;

END TEST_SYS
```

value assignment seems does not happen in the following statement. Does anybody has a clue on this?

```
temp_val := svalues_(1);
```

This example only for problem replicate, It may be not logically enhanced one. only to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have a package `test_sys` with code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_SYS IS
  PROCEDURE test( val_ OUT VARCHAR2);
END TEST_SYS;
```

and body of the package :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_SYS IS
 TYPE line_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE test( val_ OUT VARCHAR2) IS
   temp_val    varchar2(4000);
   svalues_    line_Table;
BEGIN
   svalues_(1) := '! -$FILE_LINE=EXT01;2017-01;2017-12;JJ01;;4021;;;;;;;;;;;;USD;;;;;;;;1000;1000;; -';

   temp_val := svalues_(1);
   val_ := temp_val;
   dbms_output.put_line(val_);
END test;

END TEST_SYS;
```

and call procedure `test`, you will be able to get the results as in the following :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> var str varchar2(4000);
SQL> exec test_sys.test(:str);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
str
---------
! -$FILE_LINE=EXT01;2017-01;2017-12;JJ01;;4021;;;;;;;;;;;;USD;;;;;;;;1000;1000;; -
```